# Should I use "What is the difference..." or "What are the differences..." if I don't know how many difference(s) there is/are?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

If I want to ask a question about the difference(s) between A and B, but not sure about there is only one difference or many, should I use "What is the difference between A and B" or "What are the differences between A and B"? I have searched on https://linggle.com/, both forms are frequently used.

Similar examples include "What reasons cause..." or "What reason causes...", and "Who want..." or "Who wants...".

Comment: It depends on whether you expect the differences to be countable or uncountable.  And whether you want an enumeration or just an overall assessment.

Answer (score -1):

```
What are the differences between A and B?
```

Is typically used when the number of differences are unknown.